# ShellExecute Fails if Run from Application Launched as Administrator

Tags: c++, pdf, windows-10, shellexecute, adobe-reader

My C++ application uses `ShellExecute` to open a PDF file. I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC (version 1809, OS build 17763.615) to run my application. If my application is launched as Admin (right-click `Run as administrator`) then it fails to open the PDF file. However, if my application is launched **without Admin rights** (just double-clicking it) then Adobe (the default PDF reader) is launched successfully and the PDF is displayed correctly.

My application runs normally (with and without `Run as admin`) on Windows 7 and Windows 10 Pro. This issue just started happening now that we are trying to use Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC.

The actual code from my application is:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, full_path.toWideCharPointer(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

where `full_path` is for example equal to `"C:\\Faxitron\\Docs\\Guide.pdf"`.

In both cases (admin or not), `ShellExecute` always returns 42 and `GetLastError` returns 0. Here is something interesting: when running my application as Admin, the Task Manager shows 2 processes of `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (32 bit)` under my application, but the program Adobe is never launched/opened.

Not sure if this is relevant or not, but I'm using the latest version of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 19.012.20034).

Finally, my application requires to be run as Admin (for other functionality to work properly). Is there a way to get `ShellExecute` to work when running application as administrator?

Comment: Have you tried to launch Adobe.exe with arguments Guide.pdf instead ?

Comment: [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) on second argument, it seems you can provide `open` command, have you tried ? I know that windows fallback on many object when you are using `NULL` parameters, but it could worth it to provide them yourself.

Comment: I tried launching `AcroRd32.exe` (which is apparently the Adobe command) with the PDF as arguments and that didn't work. Using `open` didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `ShellExecute` cannot launch the PDF viewer from an *elevated process*, in this case, is because Adobe Reader is preventing it via its **Protected Mode**. To solve this issue disable protected mode by doing the following:

1. Open Adobe Reader.
2. Choose **Edit > Preferences...**
3. In the **Categories** list on the left, select **Security (Enhanced).**
4. In the **Sandbox Protections** section, *deselect* **Enable Protected Mode at startup**
5. Click **OK** to save the changes.
6. Close Adobe Reader.

For more information about **Protected Mode** (and possible vulnerabilities) refer to this link from Adobe.com:
https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/protectedmode.html